# What kind of insect appears in this photo?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

For months my wife has been commenting about a white substance spontaneously appearing on black clothes. Under magnification, the substance appears to possibly be eggs. As you can see, the image shows a structure smaller than 0,1mm on her jeans fabric.

[image: Image of object suspected of being an egg.]

My clothes are unaffected. We live in Neugraben, a south-west suburb of Hamburg. We do not have any pets.

Comment: You'd be surprised how often it happens that people forget to post an image of what they're referring to.  When you add yours, could you also fill us in with a few details about where in the world are you - which country and if you're in the city, the suburbs, the countryside for visits. Do you have any pets or pests around the house/loft/walls?

Comment: Friendly note on English time expressions of this type, which are one of the top three traps for non-native speakers in my experience (in an international science laboratory). "Seit zwei Monate", "depuis deux moins", "da due mese" translate into English with the pronoun "for" — never "since". (And generally with a past tense, here a past continuous "has been complaining".)

Comment: #1: I am living in Neugraben, a south-west suburb of Hamburg. We do not have any pets.

Comment: looks like a ball of lint to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]I think these could be the eggs of woolly aphids(Eriosma lanigerum), which overwinter and spend their winter as either nymph or egg , woolly aphids usually lay their eggs in autumn .They are mostly attached to the stem of young plants and some species on Apple trees also and their size is about 0.3mm to 0.6mm (of eggs).
These are not harmful or poisonous to humans and not so for trees but species are like **Eriosma americanum** "Eriosoma lanigerum - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eriosoma_lanigerum